# How to get the currency symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to pass the currency symbol to a `UILabel`. When I try getting the symbol, I get weird results. Here is my code:

```
self.currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[self.currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[self.currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[self.currencyFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[self.currencyFormatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
[self.currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSLog(@"%@", self.currencyFormatter.positiveFormat);
```

The output of the `NSLog` is: `¤#,##0.00`. I'm trying to get `$`.

How can I get `$` (that's for USA)?

Comment: Why do you need a separate symbol? `NSLocaleCurrencySymbol` key for NSLocale is probably the best way to get it, but if you're trying to format a price for in-app items, you should better use `SKProduct.priceLocale` for it

Comment: The reason I want this, is because I have a UITextField, and a UILabel. The label is gonna take the symbol and the textField will be an amount of money. Therefore I need to know which side the label should be on. You're probably wondering why I just skip the label and format the textField? The answer is, because it's just impossible for me to implement. I tried it for days without success. That's why I'm gonna do this "hack".

Comment: You are definitely doing it wrong! Currency symbol may appear both to the left and to the right sides of money string. Instead of splitting the visual appearance into `UITextField` and `UILabel`, I encourage you to use text validation via `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method. The validation is trivial - get the numbers, format the string as money and replace the text in input if it differs from the result.

Comment: @Sega-Zero Thanks for the response!! I tried that, and I get weird results. Here is a sample project, https://jumpshare.com/b/PSW9i0N012RSgzFoW6Eb. Thanks!!

Comment: When your input is firstResponder - just don't display currency symbol. Next, disallow entering all non-numbers symbols (except decimal separator). When the keyboard dismisses, reformat the text with the currency sign. I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4850969/1254172) answer will help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you seek is named [`currencySymbol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/currencySymbol). Or possibly [`internationalCurrencySymbol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/internationalCurrencySymbol).