# Code is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In the method of `shouldChnageTextInRange`, I have a block of code validating a `textField` for currency input. I then tried getting an `NSLog` from a `textField`, but I never get results.

Here is my edited code I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342181/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-currency-input-in-uitextfield/4850969#4850969):

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == self.myTextField)
    {
        static NSString *numbers = @"0123456789";
        static NSString *numbersPeriod = @"01234567890.";
        static NSString *numbersComma = @"0123456789,";   

        if (range.length > 0 && [string length] == 0) {
            // enable delete
            return YES;
        }

        NSString *symbol = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
        if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:symbol]) {
            // decimalseparator should not be first
            return NO;
        }
        NSCharacterSet *characterSet;
        NSRange separatorRange = [textField.text rangeOfString:symbol];
        if (separatorRange.location == NSNotFound) {
            if ([symbol isEqualToString:@"."]) {
                characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:numbersPeriod] invertedSet];
            }
            else {
                characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:numbersComma] invertedSet];              
            }
        }
        else {
            // allow 2 characters after the decimal separator
            if (range.location > (separatorRange.location + 2)) {
                return NO;
            }
            characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:numbers] invertedSet];               
        }
        return ([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterSet] length] > 0);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
}
```

The last `NSLog` never gets called. What can I do to fix that? (I set the `delegate` to self.)

Comment: Need to see when this 'self.mytextfield' get set,as everytime this condition is getting result true so you are not geting last line log. Because art at end of if there is return statement. I doubt you my setting self.myTextfield in beginediting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the code before return.

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"%@", textField.text); //before return
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I need it after. Do you know which one is returning yes? (I inserted numbers only

Comment: you have only one `return YES;`, just put the `NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);` before the line.

Comment: Are you talking about at the very beginning: `if (range.length > 0 && [string length] == 0)`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what's stopping it is the very last return statement. The one right before the `NSLog`.

Comment: What I'm really trying to achieve is to validate the textFeilds from a form like this: `myButton.enabled = (myTextField1.text.length && myTextField2.length);` And it's not working correctly because it's returning Yes at some point.

Comment: sorry, i miss `return ([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterSet] length] > 0);` if result>0,it will also return YES.

Answer (score 0):

once method return it is not executed the next line code . in your code some little mistake correct it  code  NSLog(@"%@", textField.text); should before code  return ([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:characterSet] length] > 0);